Navigation destination Optional tried to update multiple times per frame
I'm working on a Match Prediction pulling data from an API and am getting this error: Navigation destination Optional<TeamView> tried to update multiple times per frame.
I have tried encapsulating the MatchPredictionsView in a NavigationLink but that does not fit the UI scheme for PlayerCards. I'm confused because the data populating the player cards and Coach has already been loaded and I'm not updating the view after it appears. If someone could provide some feedback about how not to encounter this issue in the future it would be much appreciated.
Here is my code:
struct TeamView: View {
    let team: Team
    @State private var teamImage: UIImage? = nil
    @State var displayPredictions: Bool = false
    @State var processing: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if processing {
                ProgressView()
            }
            else {
                ZStack {
                    VStack {
                        // Header Content
                        if let teamImage = teamImage {
                            Image(uiImage: teamImage)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .padding()
                        } else {
                            // Fallback image or placeholder if the image couldn't be loaded
                            Image(systemName: "photo")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                .padding()
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    // Rest of content
                    ScrollView {
                        Spacer(minLength: 350)
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                .shadow(radius: 7.5, y: -10)
                            VStack {
                                // Team Name
                                Text(team.name)
                                    .font(.title)
                                    .padding()
                                // Manager
                                Text("Manager: \(team.coach.name)")
                                    
                                // Roster
                                Text("Roster")
                                    .font(.title3)
                                ForEach(team.squad, id: \.id) { player in
                                    PlayerCard(player: player)
                                        .padding()
                                }
                                
                                // Match Predictions
                                NavigationLink(destination: MatchPredictionsView(team: team)) {
                                    ZStack {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                                            .foregroundStyle(.green)
                                            .frame(width: 350, height: 100)
                                        
                                        Text("Predict Future Matches")
                                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                            .font(.title2)
                                    }
                                }
                                .padding()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            processing = true
            await loadImage()
            processing = false
        }
    }
    
    func loadImage() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: team.crestURL) else { return }

        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.teamImage = image
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed to load image: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

PlayerCard:

struct PlayerCard: View {
    var player: Player
    @State var positionAbbrevation: String = ""
    @State var processing: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if processing {
                ProgressView()
            }
            else {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .shadow(radius: 10)
                HStack {
                    Text(positionAbbrevation)
                    Text(player.name)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 350, height: 100)
        .task {
            processing = true
            positionAbbrevation = await positionAbbreviation(position: player.position)
            processing = false
        }
    }
    
    func positionAbbreviation(position: String) async -> String {
        switch position {
        case "Goalkeeper":
            return "GK"
        case "Defence":
            return "D"
        case "Right-Back":
            return "RB"
        case "Centre-Back":
            return "CB"
        case "Left-Back":
            return "LB"
        case "Midfield":
            return "M"
        case "Attacking Midfield":
            return "CAM"
        case "Left Winger":
            return "LW"
        case "Right Winger":
            return "RW"
        case "Offence":
            return "ST"
        default:
            return position
        }
    }
}

Here is the View where TeamView gets called:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var teamsArray: [Team] = []
    // for procesing fetch request from json URL
    @State private var processing: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    if processing {
                        ProgressView()
                    }
                    else {
                        ForEach(teamsArray, id: \.id) { team in
                            NavigationLink(destination: TeamView(team: team), label: { TeamCard(team: team) })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            processing = true
            let response: TeamApiResponse? = await fetchTeam(urlString: "https://api.football-data.org/v4/competitions/PL/teams")
            if let teamResponse = response?.teams {
                teamsArray = teamResponse
            }
            processing = false
        }
        
    }
    
    func fetchTeam<T: Decodable>(urlString: String) async -> T? {
        // Create the URL from the provided urlString
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("Invalid URL string")
            return nil
        }
        
        // Create a URLRequest object
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        // Add the API key to the request header
        request.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Auth-Token")
        
        do {
            // Perform the network request
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            
            // Check if the response status code is 200 (OK)
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                print(URLError(.badServerResponse))
                return nil
            }
            
            // Decode the data into the specified type
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            // Handle errors during the request or decoding
            print("----> error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}


First fix @State var team: Team to be let team: Team

Next you’ll either need @StateObject instead of .onAppear for your async callback or learn async/await and use .task instead which has a built in automatic object.

@malhal I've updated my code using async/await and it is still encountering the same error. Can you provide an example?

Change NavigationView to the new NavigationStack

loadImage Isn’t valid async/await code

Can you show the code where and how you call TeamView (the subject of the error), for example, is it also inside a ForEach and  NavigationView?

Note, NavigationView is deprecated you should use NavigationStack.
Also you should have only the NavigationStack in your ContentView,
not another nested one in your TeamView, try removing that one.
If need be, use NavigationStack(path: ...).
See NavigationStack
